# Как сделать чтобы before сдвигал весь блок, а не только первую строку

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Как сделать чтобы before сдвигал весь блок, а не только первую строку? нужно чтобы текст был одной ровной колонкой (следующая строка ровно под первой), а слева полоска размеры ее указаны в css, при наведении она должна увеличиться и сместить весь блок с текстом, а не только первую строку.

```css
li {
  padding-top: 22px;
  width: 300px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  margin: auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #08131f;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

a:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 10px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #d5d5d5;
}

a:hover:before {
  transition: 0.4s;
  content: "";
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 25px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #e60000;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-3">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-child-item">Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Псевдоэлемент-то у вас инлайн-блок, а вот **содержимое** `<a>` - инлайн. Вот оно и ведет себя как инлайн. Оберните его в инлайн-блок или используйте что-то такое (стили вычистил от лишнего):

```
a.dropdown-child-item {display: inline-flex;}

a.dropdown-child-item:before {
    content: "";
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 10px;
    height: auto;
    background: #d5d5d5;
}

a.dropdown-child-item:hover:before {
    transition: 0.4s;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 25px;
    background: #e60000;
}
```

Нюанс: свойство `transition: 0.4s;` лучше перенести в селектор `a.dropdown-child-item:before`, а то при убирании мыши `before` не плавно уезжает назад, а резко прыгает.